# Complete linegraph is not plotted using primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot, linechart

Hi I am trying to plot linegraph using primefaces. But I am getting the graph for 1st quadrant but I have data for 4th quadrant as well.
My code is:

Bean class:

private LineChartModel lineModel1;

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createLineModels();
}

public LineChartModel getLineModel1() {
    return lineModel1;
}



private void createLineModels() {
    lineModel1 = initLinearModel();
    lineModel1.setTitle("Linear Chart");
    lineModel1.setLegendPosition("e");
    Axis yAxis = lineModel1.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(-10);
    yAxis.setMax(10);


}

private LineChartModel initLinearModel() {
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();

    LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
    series1.setLabel("Series 1");

    series1.set(1, -2);
    series1.set(0, 1);
    series1.set(1, 3);




    model.addSeries(series1);


    return model;
}
```

The output Graph looks like this:
[Generated Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPiRc.png)

Comment: Did you analyze the generated html client-side? And check the browser javascript console? And edit the class... add annotations etc... And what if you add a dummy `p:inputText`?

Comment: Hi,It was my mistake as I did not upload the image correctly.
Now you can see the problem with graph. Please let me know what is the issue as graph is not plotted for all the three data.